# How to get BitPay to process each settlement using a new address?

Tags: bitpay, address-reuse

Since receiving multiple payments using the same address isn't safe, is there a way to get BitPay to settle the balance using a new address each time? It wouldn't be feasible for the user to log in and submit the new address manually every time. Is there a secure API for this?

Thanks

Comment: Receiving multiple payments at the same address isn't "unsafe," though it does decrease anonymity. _Spending_ multiple times from the same address _may_ be unsafe if your wallet software isn't properly crafted to produce unique `k` (nonce) values for each ECDSA signing (see http://rdist.root.org/2010/11/19/dsa-requirements-for-random-k-value/).

Comment: Yes, deanonymity is my concern.